# How to use form ajax so a click on checkbox "A" posts the content of textfield "B"?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm trying to get the value of textfield "B" when checkbox "A" is toggled.

Both fields are wrapped in a fieldset who's content is replaced by the callback output.

So far I can get both fields to replace on checkbox "B" toggle, however textfield "A" has the original value in the $form_state['values'] array.

I am having trouble finding the right way to tell the ajax for "B"
 to also post the value of "A" to callback.

Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: I've never had to do this. You could do it using jQuery, but I am not sure if that's the "Drupal way" for this.

Comment: @NoSssweat do you have an example of how to use JQuery with the ajax form callbacks? I wasn't sure if I could just post data to the callback

Comment: you can use the [.ajaxComplete() function](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/#entry-examples)

Comment: @dibs can you add the code you have so far into your question?